# laravel set model for an exist database

Tags: php, laravel

I am learning laravel and I have a local database and wanna performing CRUD operation with it through laravel, I am wondering how can I create a model for that database tables?

I am attempting to create a model on the fly via artisan:

```
php artisan make:model local_database_user
```

but this user model won't represent for the user table in my database even I made all the configuration in `.env` file.

I am wondering how my `local_database` model can really represent my database so I can use the eloquent methods with it?

Comment: **Model** represent a 'table' in database not the whole database..

Comment: yes, my mistakes, i want to set a model for the username table from my database, how to set the connection between them?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#defining-models

Comment: Read up on [Eloquent here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent).

Comment: I just want to select data from the local database and represent into the view page i have created, not intend to create any migration first.

Comment: No need to create migrations since you already have an existing database.

Comment: in most case, one model = one table, user model = user table, post model = post table,.....etc

Answer (score 4):

After setting up the connection in your `.env` file, you could set the name of the associated table in your Model using `$table` variable, like :

```
class ModelName extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'username'; //table_name
}
```

**NOTE:** Like @MartinHenriksen says

> it easier to just follow model naming conventions so table property is
>   automatically generated, so if your table is named user_admins call
>   your model UserAdmin and you won't have to explicitly define it

Comment: Most of the time i find it easier to just follow model naming conventions so table property is automatic generated, so if you table is named user_admins call your model UserAdmin and you won't have to explicit define it

Comment: That true @MartinHenriksen